# Hands On Guided Project (nulls in Year To Date Sales ( YTD Sales))

Tags: graph, project, data-analysis, sparklines, coursera-api

I'm getting nulls when i created YTD sales, and a blank graph due to the nulls from the YTD Sales. The IF statement below is what i used, and i don't know if I'm missing something.

code:

IF YEAR ([Order Date]) = YEAR (TODAY())
then [Sales]
END